# Restoring drive image on a different partition/drive letter

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-backup

In Windows 7 using Macrium I did full image backup of C: drive. Backup was saved on D: drive. I then restored it on G: drive. All drives are partitions on the same physical disk.

I then ran EasyBCD and created new boot entry that pointed at the G: drive. I then rebooted and picked new boot entry when boot menu came up.

After a lot of disc thrashing OS finally booted but I was faced with this:

1. What used to be G: was now E: (not really a problem). What used to be C: was now still C:
2. A lot of things in restored OS still pointed to C: drive. For instance when I looked at PATH environment variable some of items there pointed at E: and others would point to C:. Same for the other system environment variables:

   ```
   windir=E:\Windows

   ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
   ```

What happened is somewhat understandable because, I imagine, some of these were saved in the registry as they were (pointing to C:) and others were assigned when OS booted.

However, this can cause whole bunch of problems. I searched for a solution and it seems for things to work properly I need to reassign drive C: to the current bootable drive using procedure described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223188).

Questions:

1. Is this all there is to it (change drive letters in the registry) to "fix" restored OS instance?
2. If I do this - will this affect drive assignment when I boot into original OS (really undesirable because I would like both OS-es to be functional)?  I don't think it will because the change was local to the registry of restored OS but I can't try this now because I can't afford to screw up my original OS.
3. Maybe there is a whole different way to resolve this?

Comment: More information on the partitions are required.  I hope you have a backup because the problems you face are caused by the tool you used.

Answer (score 0):

If you migrate system this way, don't change system drive letter, if you really don't have to.
In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` those letters are assigned to specific partition on specific disk. So now it's still using original system files, because new installation have paths in registry set with `C:`, which is mapped to original system partition.

This solution provides a way to set things right, without changing a system drive letter.

1. Boot into original Windows
2. Run `Regedit`, select `HKLM`, choose `File -> Load Hive`, then select `System` hive file from new installation, in your case `G:\Windows\System32\config\System` and name it whatever you like.
3. Browse through loaded hive to `[whatever you name it to]\MountedDevices`, there rename `C:` key to `G:` and vice versa.
4. Now boot into new system and you should have a same drive assignment

I recommend to remove original disk and try to boot new installation, to check if all paths are allright.